# Random spanning tree of a rectangular grid

Tags: code-golf, grid, random, graph-theory

Significantly harder version of [Spanning tree of a rectangular grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195408/78410).

### Background

A spanning tree ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree)) of an undirected graph is a subgraph that is a tree which includes all of the vertices of the original graph. The following is an example of a spanning tree of a 4-by-4 grid graph.

[image]

### Task

Given two positive integers `w` and `h`, output **a randomly generated spanning tree of the grid graph** which has `w` vertices horizontally and `h` vertices vertically. Your program/function should be able to generate **every possible spanning tree with nonzero probability**.

One possible algorithm to solve this task is [random minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_minimum_spanning_tree), which calculates the minimum spanning tree of the given graph with randomized edge weights.

### Input and output

The input is two positive integers `w` and `h`.

The output is a representation of a spanning tree. You can choose any representation that can describe such a graph without ambiguity, which includes (but is not limited to):

- ASCII-formatted grid
- A standard graph structure, e.g. adjacency matrix, adjacency list, incidence matrix...
- A list of pairs of numbered vertices

Please specify the output format in your submission.

### Scoring & winning criterion

The standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest valid submission in bytes wins.

### Example I/O

#### `w=3, h=2`

- ASCII grid

```
+-+-+
| |
+ +-+
```

- Adjacency matrix

```
0 1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0
```

- List-of-vertex-pairs representation

```
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4), (4, 5)]
```

or

```
[((0, 0), (0, 1)),
 ((0, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((0, 1), (0, 2)),
 ((0, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((1, 1), (1, 2))]
```

#### `w=1, h=1`

The graph is a single vertex with no edges, and its only spanning tree is the graph itself.

Comment: See my answer; are complex number coordinates to distinguish vertices allowed?

Comment: @ValueInk Yes, it's allowed.

Comment: As the challenge stands now, I could generate graphs randomly, check if the current graph is a spanning tree, else repeat. The program will have random running time (usually very large), but will finish [with probability 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely). You may want to rule that out (not sure how). Or is that acceptable?

Comment: @LuisMendo I was about to go write an algorithm doing exactly like that to make a point... BogoSpanningTree

Comment: The randomness part of the challenge seems needlessly tacked on to a perfectly fine challenge.

Comment: Is it acceptable for my ASCII grid to bordered by whitespace on all sides?

Comment: @Neil Yes, it's fine.

Comment: @LuisMendo I have no problem with such a solution (though the challenge was indeed inspired from the "minimum random spanning tree" Wikipedia article).

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 134 bytes

```python
from random import*
w,h=input();w+=1
t={1}
while 1:z=choice([{a,b}for a in t for b in{a-1,a+1,a-w,a+w}-t if b%w>0<b<w*h]);print z;t|=z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZNCsIwEEDhfU8xG6E/KZi6s40XERdJbcmATUIYGUzt2WNcPL4XPmS9G3Jeo98gavcs4BZ8pLZiYRW68Ka6GblTsiK1y6Nii68F5DWp2Xqcl/q@a2GO1UfQgA4I/mvK7rqXQnelnot89AS4gjnx7TyZiVv7aMYQ0RGkkb4q5XwRww8)

A small improvement over [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197624/78410) by using row size `w+1` instead of `w` and not using the zeroth column. For example, the following coordinates are used for the input `3,2`:

```python
1-2-3
| | |
5-6-7
```

Comment: Bountied! I'll keep it up for the 7 days to give you more views.

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 146 bytes

```
Block[{c,g=GridGraph@{##}},Graph[Range[1##],Join@@Reap[Do[c@n/._c:>#0[Sow[#<->n];n],{n,RandomSample@AdjacencyList[g,c@#=#]}]&@1][[2]],Options@g]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBC4IwFADgvxIMPK3SjpWxIhAiKPT4eMSYc67c29BBhPjbLbp9l8/J2Gono1Vybhb5fOq8esGouMmL3tZFL0MrRsamif8NpSSjIWMM@cVbEqLUMsDZgxK0Xj3U9sBSqPwb2H55INwR8pH4b9XeVdKFTotj/ZRKk/pc7RDBcCVYznDCRGQIsEHktxCtp0EYxGS@95YiNJClPEsR5y8)

Based on my answer to the question [Maze Generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25970/9288).

Returns a [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) object.

For example, `w = 20, h = 20` gives:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### Ruby, 159 bytes

```
->w,h{c=(v=[*1..w].product [*1..h]).product;((f,(a,b)),(g,(d,e))=c.shuffle.map{|z|[z,z.sample]};(c=c-[f,g]+[f+g];p(a,b,d,e))if(a-d).abs+(b-e).abs<2)while c[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzLCoMwEEV/xeWkjgHr0qY/EmaRxIwRlAatlfr49lSE7u45cO44229ilYrngmFzCj5K30opF5JxfDWze2cXBxJ/UQMwgkErBEKL0KAXQjk5hZm593IwcdvXXa@4yskMsfd01OCUKzRjS7nmvKU6Zvq8wDMm0TGYohHS2CkHW/hrPe5iCV3vM6dLOhLrCitKPw)

Uses simple Kruskal's algorithm with a few pessimizations (no union-find, inefficient - and non-uniform! - sampling of the purely virtual edge list, returns via stdout), at a byte cost relatively close to Value Ink's Prim implementation.

Prints each edge as a set of four lines; if you want something slightly more sensible, replace `p(a,b,d,e)` with `p [a,b,d,e]` at the cost of one byte.

Unsqueezed version:

```
->w, h{
 v=[*1..w].product [*1..h]
 c=v.product
 while c.size > 1
  (f, (a, b)), (g, (d, e)) = c.shuffle.map{|z| [z, z.sample]}
  if (a-d).abs + (b-e).abs < 2
   c = c - [f, g] + [f + g]
   p [a,b,d,e]
  end
 end
}
```

Comment: The algorithm I used has a name?? Also you should add a TIO link

Comment: +1 for the word "pessimization".

Comment: @ValueInk there are two different ways [Prim's algorithm}(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) can be turned into a maze generator algorithm. If you randomize edges once at the beginning, it returns the same distribution as Kruskal's algorithm. If you pick a random edge at each step, you get a markedly different type of maze, that prefers paths towards the origin

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 bytes

```
,þ;Z$ṡ€2ẎẊḣ1;ẎḟL’ɗÐḟ@ḣ1ʋ¥ƬƊṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/n8D7rKJWHOxc@alpj9HBX38NdXQ93LDa0BjF3zPd51DDz5PTDE4BMB5Dwqe5DS4@tOdb1cOeq////G/83AQA)

A dyadic link taking the width and height as its arguments and returning a list of pairs of vertices indicating the edges of the random minimum spanning tree. Based on [Prim’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) with the edge costs randomised.

### Explanation

```
,þ                           | Outer table using pair function
    $                        | Following as a monad:
  ;                          | - Concatenate to:
   Z                         | - Transposed table
     ṡ€2                     | Split each into overlapping lists of length 2
        Ẏ                    | Join outer lists
         Ẋ                   | Randomise order
                          Ɗ  | Following as a monad:
          ḣ1                 | - First list item (still in a list)
                        ¥Ƭ   | - Repeat following as a dyad, collecting up results, until no new result seen (will have the randomised list of vertex pairs as its right argument)
            ;          ʋ     | - Concatenate to the following as a dyad:
             Ẏ               |   - Join outer lists (making list of vertices seen so far)
                 ɗÐḟ@        |   - Keep only items from the randomised list of edges where the following is false:
              ḟ              |     - Filter out the vertices already used
               L             |     - Length
                ’            |     - Decrement by 1
                     ḣ1      |   - First list item (still in a list)
                           Ṫ | Final iteration of the above
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>185</s> 164 bytes

A huge mess. Outputs a vertex-pair list, where vertex coordinates are complex numbers in the form `x+yi`.

Long story short, it takes all vertices that have already been chosen, randomly picks a neighbor that has not been picked before, and attaches it to the graph, then repeats the process until all vertices have been chosen.

- -4 bytes by optimizing `r>=0&&i>=0` to `r|i>=0` -- If either number is negative, the bit-or will ensure that the combined result is negative.
- -17 bytes by realizing my filter function in the second neighbor check could be switched to a simple set intersection...

```ruby
->w,h,*e{*v=q=0i;d=1,-1,1i,-1i
(q=v.flat_map{|x|d.map{|c|x+c}.select{|e|r,i=e.rect;r|i>=0&&r<w&&i<h}-v}.sample
(v<<q;e<<[(d.map{|c|q+c}&v).sample,q])if q)while q;e}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwEEX3PYWroDYGbZcmXkRENI4YUGqijYrJ2W1qS@lmmIE373/1rLejZUeULbjDIeyhZpLFIm1YgqMEJ8JNcfEl06Ttq7kcqnE3q2nIuXCzXrklE/TA592AUVgwIMpdqTIiYzFCii4ICdrZSDuyGsYeLr6mVKZAae7/TNKZkA6@CJZFIFpPBksnevAcbI82v@F7QaaHmst6e8fBXylu@Bls7ccIZvTc0ws)

#### Explanation

```ruby
->w,h,*e{                                       # Proc taking 2 arguments, e=[]
         *v=q=0i;                               # Add first vertex 0+0i to list
                 d=1,-1,1i,-1i                  # Save 4 cardinal directions
(                                     )while q  # While there is a valid neighbor:
 q=                                             # Set next vertex to:
   v.flat_map{|x|d.map{|c|x+c}                  # Get all neighbors to used vertices
      .select{|e|                               # Filter neighbors by:
                 r,i=e.rect                     # Get real/imaginary components
                 r|i>=0&&r<w&&i<h               # Vertex coordinates are in-bounds
             }
      -v                                        # Filter already-used vertices
    }.sample                                    # Pick a random valid neighbor
 (                                   )if q      # If a neighbor was found:
  v<<q                                          # Add it to the vertex list
  e<<[                                          # Add an edge to the edge list.
      (                                         # First vertex of edge is:
       d.map{|c|q+c}                            # Get vertex neighbors
       &v                                       # Intersect w/ used vertices
      ).sample                                  # Pick one by random
      ,q]                                       # Second vertex of edge is neighbor
                                                # (end while)
e                                               # Return the edge list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 64 bytes

```
{e@&~~':i{@[x;&|/x=/:y;:;&/x y]}\e:0N?,/(2':'m),+'2':m:x#i:!*/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6pOdVCrq1O3yqx2iK6wVqvRr7DVt6q0trJW069QqIytjUm1MvCz19HXMFK3Us/V1NFWBzJyrSqUM60UtfQrarm40hRMFEwAIAwT4A==)

arg: `w,h` pair. result: list of vertex pairs.

`i:!*/x` create the list 0 .. (w*h)-1 and assign to `i`

`m:x#` reshape to a w-by-h matrix `m`

`2':` pairs of neighbouring rows

`+'` transpose each (make them rows of pairs)

`(` `),` prepend

`2':'m` pairs of neighbouring cells in each row

`,/` concat into a single list

`e:0N?` shuffle and assign to `e` for "edges"

`i{` `}\` scan the edges with the function in `{` `}` and a starting value `i`.
the left arg will map vertices to their "tree ids" in the forest.
initially the vertex ids and tree ids coincide.

`@[x;&|/x=/:y;:;&/x y]` amend the current forest by merging the tree(s) corresponding to the ends of the new edge

`~':` which forests match the previous ones? boolean list

`e@&~` select from `e` where not

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 136 bytes

```python
from random import*
w,h=input()
t={0}
while 1:z=choice([{a,b}for a in t for b in{a-~a%w/~w,a+a%w/~w,a-w,a+w}-t if-1<b<w*h]);print z;t|=z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcdBDoIwEEDRPaeYjQlgGwV3Qk9iXBSEdBJpm2ZIY2u5eoWFq/@@/ZAyus15dmYBJ/VrDy7WOKoLz5RAbVcqq4JEvKbCK3xP0NyDGJXBcSofUbIhzcaBBNRAcHDYGSXf5MlfNs/k@Q9@jE@cAGfe9EPva/WsOutQE4SOviLk3LLbDw)

Prints edges as two-element set of vertices given by single-number index, terminating with error. The strategy is to to build up the set of vertices `t` in the tree until it contains the whole rectangle rectangle. At each step, we add an edge to the spanning tree consisting of a vertex in `t` and one of its neighbors that's not in `t`, and we add the new vertex to `t`. We search for neighbors by adding one of `{1,-1,w,-w}` to the 1D index with some trickery to avoid unwanted wraparounds, and checking that the result lies within the bounds of the rectangle.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 142 bytes

```python
from random import*
w,h=input()
t={0}
while 1:z=choice([{a,b}for a in{k/w+k%w*1jfor k in range(w*h)}-t for b in t if(a-b)**4==1]);print z;t|=z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBDoIwEEDRPaeYjUlbSxR0JelJjIuCYEegbZoxjSBnr3T1k7f4/kvG2TqlIbgZgrbPPTh7F0gUURqF1n@I8YLUet6KaHDqobotqjMOu57dVy3bbXABNKBdx1M8jocoqnemcaf8fPUsCsO3kiBzm5kAB6bLlgtxVap68MYHtARLQz@1pFTLyx8)

Prints edges as two-element sets of complex numbers, terminating with error.

Comment: [-2 bytes to your top solution.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201493/78410)

Comment: Which means that Bubbler is eligible for a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>151 147 145</s>  143 bytes

Takes input as `(width)(height)`. Returns a list of pairs of numbered vertices.

```javascript
w=>g=h=>(m=1,n=a=[],F=v=>[++v%w&&v,--v%w&&v-1,v+w,v-w].map(V=>V<0|V/w/h|m>>V&1|Math.random()<.5||F(V,m|=1<<V,n=a.push([v,V]))))``|~n+w*h?g(h):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYy9DsIgGEV338PmwwKKP4vph1s3V5amicSfohFobIWF@Oq1xsl4c4abM5ybDro7Pq5tz5w/nYcLDhFlgwYlWBTUocaqpiUGlFWeh2nMskAZ@x4maMgjDSzW3OoWFEpVLJKax7lJVkqVibTXveEP7U7eAin4JqUSFLUJRVGoT5@3z85AFaiqybjDIb1cHmdm14AhWz0cvev8/czvvoELCDJCJr9yRWD5J9dkhAxv)

#### Commented

```javascript
w =>                        // w = width
g = h => (                  // h = height
  m = 1,                    // m = bitmask of visited vertices
  n =                       // n = number of visited vertices - 1
  a = [],                   // a[] = pairs of connected vertices
  F = v =>                  // F is a recursive function, taking the current vertex v
    [ ++v % w && v,         //   try v + 1 if (v + 1) mod w is not equal to 0
                            //   we temporarily increment v to coerce it to a number
      --v % w && v - 1,     //   decrement v; try v - 1 if v mod w is not equal to 0
      v + w,                //   unconditionally try v + w
      v - w                 //   unconditionally try v - w 
    ].map(V =>              //   for each new vertex V:
      V < 0 |               //     abort if V is negative
      V / w / h |           //     abort if V is greater than or equal to w * h
      m >> V & 1 |          //     abort if V was already visited
      Math.random() < .5 || //     abort with 50% probability
      F(                    //     otherwise, do a recursive call:
        V,                  //       using the new vertex
        m |= 1 << V,        //       update the bitmask of visited vertices
        n = a.push([v, V])  //       append [v, V] to a[] and update n
      )                     //     end of recursive call
    )                       //   end of map()
)`` |                       // initial call to F with v = [''] (zero'ish)
~n + w * h ?                // if n is not equal to w * h - 1:
  g(h)                      //   try again
:                           // else:
  a                         //   success: return a[]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>77</s> 63 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＪ⊗‽θ⊗‽ηＰ+  ¦+Ｗ‹№ＫＡ+×θη«Ｊ⊗‽θ⊗‽η¿¬℅ＫＫ«≔⌕ＡＫＶ ι¿ι«Ｐ+  Ｐ✳⁻χ⊗‽ι²+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZAxT8MwEIVn51ecMp3VIAHqBFNFhQSioUIVe5oYcsI@p3YMA@pvN3bKUKALkgffu3ffPbvtG9faRsd4x0MY62C2yuFOXhfHdZ/q@2CGjcWlDVutOnxquLMmOWUFv7ReyuRfBT3S4IhHvJpVUAKUSV1PQjnL94@etAJ8UN7jjQ1JXyv1ttAaEzNbKtiQUR53FWQmfBbivykEvQDWdsRH1xE3elqB8psmFt7TK@MtcZf35uaz5VoF0zBPMSDHoEyaUHSYE6df97OxJKfakSzjijh4vDj/E5JykgouD7PHnyPEvkhnH@Mc5vHsXX8B) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a whitespace-bordered ASCII grid. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the width and height.

```
Ｊ⊗‽θ⊗‽ηＰ+  ¦+
```

Jump to a random position and mark it with a `+` surrounded with spaces. (Unfortunately Charcoal's Multiprint operator special-cases a leading `+` so I have to output the `+` separately.)

```
Ｗ‹№ＫＡ+×θη«
```

Repeat until `w*h` `+`s have been output.

```
Ｊ⊗‽θ⊗‽η
```

Jump to a random position.

```
¿¬℅ＫＫ«
```

If the position is vacant,

```
≔⌕ＡＫＶ ι
```

find any neighbouring spaces,

```
¿ι«
```

and if there is at least one, then

```
Ｐ+  Ｐ✳⁻χ⊗‽ι²+
```

surround the current position with spaces, draw a `-` or `|` in a random matching direction, and finally draw a `+` in the current position.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 156 bytes

```r
function(w,h){b=rbind(x<-1:(s=w*h),c(x+1,1:(s-h)+h))[,1:w*-h][,sample(s+s-h-w)]
y=b[,1]
while(!all(z<-matrix(b%in%y,2)))y=rbind(y,b[,colSums(z)==1][1:2])
y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BToQwEIbvfYq1SU2ntDHFxMQNfQRPHrGHgrAlYVlC2ZSi@@w4GKPxNv/88898M22t2drrUM/dZeBReviozFR1wztfCqWPPJgoPMiaL5mWu1YeMg9QoohCeVvK4M5j3/CQoaciWJJMhbYl0XfYv3N9z9dCnd08dQuvWDewJHMASD@XksT5@tK/Xs@Br2CMtqU@5hZIum2nQv3nIwjWfpdKk7@99EClF7mMIsdcoaZLfGncEBCcL@yBeeHFI@w1Q3yyljpLtlA1p4pK@klhbzCWW7QwixwoEOUewX6FPRTqQAUltZu5G8c@8VVqObowN/sHvRtDYygFGZrR0LeBAlnIjZz4k3yG7Qs)

A function taking the width and height and returning a two-matrix of 1-indexed pairs of points (numbered from top left, moving down and then right). The footer also prints an ASCII representation. Implements [Prim’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm).